# Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK] in Android

Tags: android, admob

I am trying to implement `MobAd` functionality but i am facing error

```
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK]
```

I am not a android developer.. just want to implement the functionality can anybody help me out

Here is my `Manifest` :

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   package="com.dinesh.mobdemo" >
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
   <uses-permission    
   android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />
</application>
```

*dependencies* :

```
    dependencies {
      compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.0'
      compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.0'
      compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.1.11'
      compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.4.52'
```

}

*Layout* :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res
/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity">


<TextView android:text="@string/hello_world"   
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adMob"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-1301186605291775/1237290645" />
  </RelativeLayout>
```

and my `Strings` Values :

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <resources>

    <string name="app_name">MobDemo</string>
    <string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
   <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
   <string name="adMob">adMob</string>
  </resources>
```

please help what i am missing

Answer (score 0):

You're missing `uses-sdk` element and especially its `minSdkVersion` attribute in the manifest.

When they're missing, the min SDK level defaults to 1 which is considered "too old".

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html

The "dependencies" part suggests you're using Gradle, so the `minSdkVersion` can also be specified in your app's build.gradle file.